# sails.js - Getting blank page

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

It is properly working in my localhost. Issue only in another server.

When I run this application from another server, getting a blank page like below,

[image]

But api's are working properly. Landing page and no other pages are getting.

This issue has been started from today.
In previous days there is no problem in this server.

All pages shows only '304 Not Modified' status.
Undefined pages are also showing '304 Not Modified' instead of '404 not found'.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have errors turned on in the configuration?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Issue fixed.

views/layout.ejs get automatically empty that's why this issue occurred.

Reset the file to fix the issue.

Comment: Did it happen again on "sails lift"?

Comment: How did yout reset the file?

Comment: Use this link to reset the file.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rollbar/rollbar-sailsjs-example/master/views/layout.ejs

Comment: If you're using Git, you can do `git checkout views/layouts/layout.ejs`